# No_output_displaying: Not able to implement detector module in face recognition using tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, user-interface, tkinter, opencv3.0

Please help me....
I'm currently working a face recognition project using python,opencv and tkinter, In the project i tried to implement the detector module in tkinter but it is not working.I'm not receiving any output it works without any syntax error.When i run the code the webcam will turn on but the tkinter window wont be displayed.

```
import cv2,os
import sqlite3
import numpy as np
import tkinter as tk
import cv2
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
import pickle
import time
import datetime

width, height = 800, 600
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, width)
cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, height)
recognizer = cv2.face.LBPHFaceRecognizer_create()
recognizer.read('trainer/trainer.yml')
cascadePath = "Classifiers/face.xml"
faceCascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier(cascadePath);
path = 'dataSet'


root = tk.Tk()
root.bind('<Escape>', lambda e: root.quit())
lmain = tk.Label(root)
lmain.pack()

btn = tk.Button(root, text="End", command=root.destroy)
btn.pack(fill="both", expand=True, padx=10, pady=10)

def getProfile(Id):
    conn=sqlite3.connect("facebase.db")
    cmd="SELECT * FROM people WHERE ID="+str(Id)
    cursor=conn.execute(cmd)
    profile=None
    for row in cursor:
        profile=row
    conn.close()
    return profile 



#def show_frame():
    #_, frame = cap.read()
    #frame = cv2.flip(frame, 1)
    #cv2image = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGBA)
    #img = Image.fromarray(cv2image)
    #imgtk = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image=img)
    #lmain.imgtk = imgtk
    #lmain.configure(image=imgtk)
    #lmain.after(10, show_frame)
def show_frame():

    dt=datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%d-%m-%y")
    tm=datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%H:%M")
    cam = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
    fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'XVID')
    out = cv2.VideoWriter('output.avi',fourcc, 4, (640,480))
    font = cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX #Creates a font
    while True:
        ret, im =cam.read()
        gray=cv2.cvtColor(im,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
        faces=faceCascade.detectMultiScale(gray, 1.2,5)
        for(x,y,w,h) in faces:
            cv2.rectangle(im,(x,y),(x+w,y+h),(225,0,0),2)
            Id, conf = recognizer.predict(gray[y:y+h,x:x+w])
            if(conf<60):
                    profile=getProfile(Id)
            else:
                    Id=0
                    profile=getProfile(Id)
            if(profile!=None):
                cv2.rectangle(im, (x-22,y-90), (x+w+80, y-22), (0,255,0),-1)
                cv2.putText(im,str(profile[0]), (x,y-40), font, 2,(255,255,255), 3)
                cv2.putText(im,str(profile[1]), (x+50,y-40), font, 2,(255,255,255), 3)
                connt=sqlite3.connect("facebase.db")
                c=connt.cursor()
                c.execute('''INSERT INTO detected(Id, name, Date, Time)
                        VALUES(?,?,?,?)''', (profile[0],profile[1], dt, tm))
                connt.commit()
                connt.close()

        #out.write(im)
        #cv2.imshow('im',im)
        #cv2image = cv2.cvtColor(im, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGBA)
        img = Image.fromarray(im)
        imgtk = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image=img)
        lmain.imgtk = imgtk
        lmain.configure(image=imgtk)
        #lmain.after(10, show_frame)
        #if cv2.waitKey(10) & 0xFF==ord('q'):
            #break
        lmain.after(10, show_frame)


show_frame()
root.mainloop()
cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

[image]

I'm currently using python 3.4 and opencv 3.4 can anybody help me i'm new in python and tkinter

thank you........

Comment: What about other errors? Can you type in the command prompt/shell while it's running?

Comment: i have updated the question with screenshot of shell.when i run the code the web cam will turn on but it won't display any tkinter window. @ArtemisFowl

Comment: And yes i can type in command prompt/shell while it's runs @ArtemisFowl

Comment: You've got an infinite loop somewhere...

Answer (score 0):

In `def showframe()`, you have an infinite loop (`while True:`) so the program never gets to `mainloop()`, and so never creates the tkinter window. To fix this, you could create a button the user presses to start the infinite loop, meaning that it **can** only start once the tk window has appeared.

Comment: So how do you propose rectify it? @ArtemisFowl

Comment: I tried to remove the loop but webcam is just flashing nothing else. @ArtemisFowl

Comment: yeah i think it's one of the reasons but now a window would pop up and freeze. i have moved out cam = cv2.VideoCapture(0),fourcc =cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'XVID') and out =cv2.VideoWriter('output.avi',fourcc, 4, (640,480)) from def show_frame(): and removed the while loop @ArtemisFowl

Comment: It will be extremely grateful if you would help me out here. i kind of desperately need to fix it @ArtemisFowl....

Comment: @Abin I have added a suggestion.